# How to call the restoreCompletedTransactions

Tags: ios, ios7

i am doing one application.In that i am calling the restoreCompletedTransactions method like below.

```
-(void)restore
{
   [SKPaymentQueue defaultqueue] restoreCOmpletedTransactions];
 }
```

But it will not give any response from apple.If i d like below then app is crashing when i call the restore method.

```
-(void)restore
  {
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
   [SKPaymentQueue defaultqueue] restoreCOmpletedTransactions];
 }
```

So how to call the restoreCompletedTransactions.And when we use this [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self] in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to call  `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` in your app delegate. It is recommended to call it in `AppDidFinishLaunching`.
2. Then in your restore method (Usually connected to a button) you will call -    `[SKPaymentQueue defaultqueue] restoreCOmpletedTransactions];`
3. Do you implement the [SKProductsRequestDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequestDelegate/Reference/Reference.html) ?, what do you mean there is no response by apple ?